# How to get pc-name from IP address?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, networking, lan, ip

Anyone can tell me how to resolve pc-name for a given IP address on local area network ?

I went through many answers but no one helped me :/

I am mentioning all tricks I used below ::

```
netstat -a <ip>

nmblookup -A <ip>

host <ip>

nbtscan <ip>

nbtscan <ip>

arp -a

nmap -sP <ip>
```

No one resolved name of pc corresponding to given IP address.

Thanking you in advance!!

Let me know In case If you want to see output for a particular command.

Comment: Try to get with Windows  _ping -a ipaddress_ Linux _nslookup ipaddress_

Comment: @RameshChand I used nslookup but it syas

`** server can't find 172.152.26.172.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux Machine you can see by typing:

```
$ nslookup 216.58.197.46
```

Output:

```
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
46.197.58.216.in-addr.arpa      name = maa03s20-in-f14.1e100.net.
```

On Windows Machine You can check it with:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping -a 216.58.197.46
```

Or

```
nslookup 216.58.197.46
```

Output:

```
Pinging maa03s20-in-f14.1e100.net [216.58.197.46] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.197.46: bytes=32 time=210ms TTL=56
Ping statistics for 216.58.197.46:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 164ms, Maximum = 230ms, Average = 205ms
```

Comment: In my case It says 



'Server:  127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find 172.152.26.172.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN'

No name :/